# Virtual column referencing another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with workday and peoples worked that day (M:N)
and table workday with attribute = "Number of people worked that day".

I want to count in M:N table all rows with same workday id and to write that count in workday table as amount of people worked like generated column.

How do I do that?

I tried something like this...

```
alter table WORKDAY
add NUM_OF_EMPLOYEES NUMBER(3) GENERATED ALWAYS AS
  (COUNT(*) FROM WORKDAY_EMPLOYEES WHERE WORKDAY_EMPLOYEES.ID = THIS.ID)
  STORED NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Create a view instead.

Comment: A "generated" column can't be based on data in a different table. jarlh gave you the solution: write a view instead. Separately - what do you mean by "sqldeveloper generated column"? What does sqldeveloper (which is a separate piece of software, which lets you interact with your Oracle database), have to do with your question?

Comment: That doesn't work. It assumes that the table workday is updated whenever workday_employees is updated - that is not the case. Instead create a view with a count for each id of table workday.

Comment: Yes i know it doesnt work i just wrote it like that so u can understand what is my goal.

Comment: Thank you for help all of u.

Comment: does anyone one of u knows how that view query should look?

Comment: okay i made it, i got the view with workday id columns and counted workers columns,

Comment: can i connect it to the table workday now?

Comment: Please don't include tags in the question title. Also, avoid referring to unrelated tools like SQL Developer unless they are related to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a view.
You will need to substitute the names of columns and table.

```
CREATE VIEW number_employees_per_day AS
SELECT 
  date_column,
  COUNT(DISTINCT employee_id)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY date_column
ORDER BY date_column;
```

Comment: can i connect it to the workday table now?

Comment: you need to modifiy the table and column names

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't know how to select the number of employees for a workday. Here is how (I had to make up the column id_workday, for there must be some columnlike this in the workday_employees to reference a workday):

```
SELECT
  w.*,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM workday_employees we 
    WHERE we.id_workday = w.id
  ) AS num_of_employees 
FROM workday w;
```

Another option:

```
SELECT
  w.*,
  COALESCE(w.total, 0) AS num_of_employees 
FROM workday w
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT id_workday, COUNT(*) AS total
  FROM workday_employees
  GROUP BY id_workday
) w ON w.id_workday = w.id;
```

Yet another option is a lateral join (`OUTER APPLY`).

Once you have the query, create a view for convenience:

```
CREATE VIEW workday_counted AS
  SELECT ... -- one of the queries above
  ;
```